# Is 125000 the maximum width whereby the border is drawn?

Tags: wpf, xaml, width

The following simple XAML puts a border on the base of a grid inside a scroll viewer and links the grid's width to the value of a slider.

```
<Window x:Class="BorderWidth.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="DrawBorder">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <Grid Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="{Binding Value, ElementName=slider}">
                <Border BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1"/>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
        <TextBox  Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Value, ElementName=slider}"/>
        <Slider x:Name="slider" Minimum="124000" Maximum="126000" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

While the width is less than 125000 the border shows, but after that value it vanishes. There is no maximum width mentioned in [the documentation for the border control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.border.aspx) and the maximum width for a control in general [is documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.width.aspx) to lie somewhere between `Single.MaxValue` and `Double.MaxValue`, i.e. far far larger than 125000. Is this 125000 upper bound a bug; or is it documented somewhere?

Comment: sounds like a real problem for 1500" monitors, I can't understand how did it get overlooked

Comment: Hence the outer `ScrollViewer`

Comment: I've lost you. There is only one textbox, it isn't part of the problem.

Comment: I got it, deleted comment. It's a test, I see that. And yet one that shows nothing useful - even if you hit an issue at double.maxvalue you're no closer to having any practical benefit from the discovery there's a lower limit than that.  It's possible the 124000 is multiplied by width and buffer for that fails to be created. Try setting the width to 1 or 5 px

Comment: You mean the height right? Setting it to 5 makes no difference. The border still vanishes when the width of the grid hits 125000. I don't understand your "no practical benefit" point. If one knows that there is an (undocumented) limit one can avoid the technique and choose an alternative in situations that exceed the limit. That strikes me as a practical benefit.

Comment: that technique is well known and commonly used to avoid heights of, say, 1500px. It's called virtualizing container and ListView is one example where it's used. It consists of rendering only what should be shown and not the other 122500 px that are not used. So - no, you're not finding out anything new here

Comment: Unfortunately the real code that this is a cut down samle of uses a Canvas as the within a data-bound ListView. Each row of the visualization is then drawn on the canvas. The visualization (which looks a bit like chromography) renders fine, even for large widths, but for widths above 125000 the border between rows disappears. I've fixed it, by using a 1px high rectangle in another 1px high row instead of the border control. But I would like to know why the border control fails.

Comment: your listview probably scrolls vertically, so it's not virtualizing the scrolling to the right. it's simply not the Right Thing to try render a canvas 124000px wide: it's a waste of memory, possible performance hog and leaves your software to possible 'disappearing border' attacks where someone delivers content above the width that Border supports. the Right Thing would be to either implement a custom control to only render parts of your data within reasonable widths OR to break down the original data into chunks and load them inside a ListView with template such that they appear contiuous

Comment: Consider this: google maps loads on a 3" phone screen somehow without requiring 5354200342px canvas